# can't deploy the project with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3

I have a ruby on rails project to be deployed with capistrano. Basically I could deploy it with the following code.

```
cap production deploy
```

But it gives me the following failure message.

```
** Invoke staging (first_time)
** Execute staging
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
cap aborted!
Capfile locked at 3.2.1, but 3.3.3 is loaded
```

I can not find anything on this exception. Do you know what is the real problem. BTW bundle update does not work.

Comment: delete `gemlock` file and `bundle` again.

Comment: It does not work with  `bundle install`.

Comment: was bundle succesfull? I see there can be defferent versions of cap in  both files

Comment: @Nithin Yes was succesfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added  `gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.2.1'`  to Gemfile. After `$ bundle update` the problem fixed.

Answer (score 5):

See your config/deploy.rb if there is something such as `lock '3.2.1'`. Because if your Gemfile has gem `capistrano, '~>3.2.1'`, it will be updated to 3.3.3 but it is locked on `deploy.rb`. Even using `lock '>=3.2.1'` i am still having problem with `.capistrano/metrics` in version 3.3.3.

Comment: I just created the folder/file .capistrano/metrics, and it works.

Comment: PS: It just worked if I remove lock or put lock '3.3.3'.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall version 3.3.3 and install 3.2.1 will solve your problem.

1: **sudo gem uninstall capistrano**

```
 select the version you want to uninstall(3.3.3 in your case)
```

Answer (score 1):

`bundle exec cap production deploy`

You need to use the `cap` command in the context of your bundle rather than the system.

Comment: I have tried it already but it can not help me. It gives the same failure message exactly.